# word wrap in ssh session not working with grep

Tags: linux, ssh, grep

When I ssh to my Linux servers and use grep like this:

grep 'timeout exceeded' logfile | less

word wrap does not work.

However, if I use the same command but use less first, like this:

less logfile | grep 'timeout exceeded'

the lines wrap. I am not sure what the problem is or if this is normal or not. But it happens regardless of the ssh client I use. I have tried both putty and an Ubuntu client. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
grep 'timeout exceeded' logfile | less
```

You can use the right arrow keys to move to the end of the line (left to move back).

Comment: Thanks. While that works and gives me the ability to see the whole line, it does not answer my question directly. Surely there is a way to force grep to word wrap?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to force grep to do it, but the *NIX utility fold seems to do it okay:  grep 'timeout exceeded' logfile | fold -s -w 150 | less

The -s tells it to break at spaces; -w COLUMNS specifies the column width.

Comment: That is so odd. I thought I was just overlooking a simple grep flag or something. Well anyway fold works fine with the arguments you provided and does accomplish what I was after. Appreciate the help!

Comment: 1) the rightmost command in a pipe is the one displaying on your screen. The left command outputs to the right command. 2) For `less`, "folding" is the default, unless you specify the `-S` or `--chop-long-lines` option. If you did not write those options in  your command then check `alias` to see if your shell has an alias that adds it, or `echo $LESS` to see if you have the option in your default command environment variable.

Comment: @DerfK - I wonder if something is set odd in my environment also; I was seeing the same behavior as OP with less not folding; that's why I added the fold to the command.

Comment: Here is what I have when using alias: alias cp='cp -i'
alias egrep='egrep --colour=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --colour=auto'
alias grep='grep --colour=auto'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias rm='rm -i'
alias s='cd ..'
And Echo $less - -iFRSX -x4
What would I need to add and where to get it to wrap lines?

Answer (score 5):

This is not the default behavior of `less`. The default is to wrap long lines.

You are seeing this behavior because you have the `-S` option (and several others) set in your `LESS` environment variable.

```
       -S or --chop-long-lines
              Causes  lines  longer than the screen width to be chopped (trun‐
              cated) rather than wrapped.  That is, the portion of a long line
              that does not fit in the screen width is not shown.  The default
              is to wrap long lines; that is, display  the  remainder  on  the
              next line.
```

To resolve the problem, check your shell startup scripts (e.g. `$HOME/.bash_profile`, `$HOME/.bashrc`) and the system shell startup scripts (e.g. those in the `/etc/profile.d` directory) to see where the environment variable is being set, and make the desired changes.

Answer (score 0):

If your `less` is defaulting to not wrapping lines, try using the full path to less.  Run `which less` and see what path it gives you.  Then use that path instead.  For example if it's at /usr/bin/less then try `grep 'timeout exceeded' logfile | /usr/bin/less`.